# What methods could I use to dynamically apply a sepia tone to an image in to a web page using PHP?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, filter, photo

I have a webpage that loads thumbnails of images and I want to show old images with a sepia tone. The thumb will always be the same dimensions so could I just make a transparent png file and show it over the image? Should I use something like imagemagick or is this overkill?

Any suggestions?
Cheers

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the ImageMagick library, you could try [Imagick::sepiaToneImage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-sepiatoneimage.php).

See:

http://eclecticdjs.com/mike/tutorials/php/imagemagick/examples_03/sepia.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a sepia image with transparency, you can only darken it or shift the colors a bit, but it wouldn't make a real sepia. But it is a simpler and lighter solution.